# Ideal method for heavy logging with POSIX thread(s)?

Tags: c, multithreading

I've tried and tried to find a pre-existing discussion about this on SO and the Internet in general.  Maybe I'm not doing it right, because it's hard to believe this hasn't been addressed for the basic C language.

I have some computationally-simple code which nonetheless requires a lot of logging to be performed.  This logging is currently making my code run 10x slower.  Obviously the solution is to break logging into a separate thread or process. Using a separate process requires a lot of platform-specific mumbo-jumbo and I need this code to remain as portable as possible (currently developing in OS X, to be ported to Windows later). So I've just started learning about threading and pthread.h.

Just to be clear, unlike some existing pthread discussions on the Internet, we're talking about straight writing to a file here, not I/O. The log file never needs to be read by the program. What I'm doing at the moment is:

```
/* Called many times a second; a few minutes of program usage will make
a couple megs of text in the log file */
void MyLogFunction(char *format, ...)
{
    char buffer[1024];
    va_list arglist;

    va_start(arglist, format);
    vsnprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1, format, arglist);
    va_end(arglist);

    pthread_t threadID;
    pthread_create(&threadID, NULL, WriteLog, &buffer);
}

/* As written, this function writes unpredictable contents to disk because
I passed it a pointer to a local variable that is getting modified
constantly by the main thread; I know I should be doing something like
allocating new blocks of memory within MyLogFunction() for each pthread,
so let's pretend I'm doing that and move on with the discussion ;-) */
void *WriteLog(void *string)
{
    pthread_detach(pthread_self());
    fprintf(gLogHandle, "%s: %s\n",
      /* OS X time-to-string stuff omitted here */,
      (char *)string);
    fflush(gLogHandle);

    return NULL;
}
```

I'm concerned about two things:

A. It seems unwise to spawn up to dozens of pthreads each second. Is it?

B. The messages will probably get written out of order sometimes, right?

This leads me to ask these three questions:

1. Should I be making one logging thread that stays open?  How can it know when to write another line without polling rapidly? I can't leisurely poll some `gNewLineIsAvailableToWrite` bool because this code sometimes crashes and I can't afford to miss the last logging messages before the crash. Also, the creation of new lines in the log spikes every few ticks to a peak of maybe 20 lines per tick.
2. Should I make separate pthreads as currently shown, but give them each others' IDs and tell them to `pthread_join()` so that they wait for the previous thread to finish before writing their line? This still results in a proliferation of threads but at least they would write in order, eh?
3. Or am I looking at this problem all wrong?

Comment: Writing to a file **is** I/O.

Comment: You don't have to do both input and output to count as I/O - either counts.

Comment: Ah, okay. I didn't phrase that well, then, but I wanted to distinguish this issue from the discussions I've seen about using threads to read in and parse data, which is a more complex problem than the one I'm trying to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes.  It will know when to write another line when you use some form of inter-thread comms that allows it to wait on a producer-consumer queue for log *structs.

2) NO!!  Do not continually create/terminate/destroy threads.  Don't go near join().  Just create ONE logging thread, once, at startup, and queue your log requests to it.

Or, of course, find a logging lib that already works :)

Another hint: you could add a 'command' enum to your struct that tells the logging thread what to do. Surely, most of the ime it would be 'log the string in my buffer', but you could add other commands to, say, flush the log file, open a new log file using a new path/filename in the buffer, open a new log file after X MB or every X hours, whatever.  The 'slack' of the queue would allow 'lengthy' file operations without any effect on the performance of the threads requesting the logging.

Comment: Okay, I'm glad I asked the question. I completely forgot to look into the subject of inter-thread communication. I spent all day yesterday reading about IPC so I should have thought of this. Looks like I need to read about pthread_cond_wait() and pthread_cond_signal().

Answer (score 1):

Creating a *separate* thread every time you plan to log a line is clearly suboptimal (let alone subject to mangled output from multiple threads). *One* of the approaches to logging in a multithreaded application is to log into an internal (often circular) buffer which is flushed periodically by a specially designated thread. As a result, your "I/O" cost for logging in each thread goes down dramatically (although formatting still takes a toll). However you would have to pay for competing for the logging resource (the buffer). There are also some approaches to mitigate it but some cost will still be there.

Having said all of the above, it is difficult to assess the right way to deal with it without looking at the performance profile of your program - how many threads, what they compete for etc. If I were you, I'd start with *trying* a ready-to-use logging infrastructure like [log4cpp](http://log4cpp.sourceforge.net/). A lot of people have already solved the problems you are facing and there is little reason to re-invent it all over again. Try using it, then see where your bottlenecks are.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I may use a library like that after all (and I see there's "log4c" as well, for troglodytes like me). Unfortunately that one is LGPL and I don't know if I should open-source the code I'm writing, but maybe I will.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Should I be making one logging thread that stays open?

Yes, the usual approach is to have a single, long-lived logging thread.

> ... How can it know when to write another line without polling rapidly?

The standard solution is to use a shared logging queue protected by a mutex, and an associated condition variable to wake the logging thread (optimally, you only need to do this when the queue *stops being empty*).

> ... Also, the creation of new lines in the log spikes every few ticks to a peak of maybe 20 lines per tick.

Try to make sure whatever shared queue you use can absorb those spikes, and note there's no reason why the logging thread must only consume one message per lock/wait/unlock cycle.